# Information from my object filled observable array won't show up in my view

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I have found similair questions about the problem I'm having here on SO, but none of them fixed my problem.

When I load the page, I retrieve an array of objects from the database using AJAX. They have the properties `ID`,`name` and `score`.

The array will be put in a variable called `hs`.
When I `console.log` the variable `hs`, it logs the array with the objects inside, so that can not be the problem. (Right?)

Now, when I load the page, it doesn't show the information from those objects. That is the issue I'm experiencing!

This is a piece of my viewmodel:

```
 function initCanvas() {
    this.playerName = ko.observable("");
    this.chosenLevel = ko.observable();
    this.chosenDifficulty = ko.observable();

    this.availableLevels = ko.observableArray(['Mountains', 'Stars', 'Jungle']);
    this.difficulty = ko.observableArray(['Makkelijk', 'Normaal', 'Moeilijk']);
    this.highscores = ko.observableArray(hs);
    this.personalHighScore = ko.observable(localStorage.getItem("+score") || "Geen record!");
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
        <table>             
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: highscores">
                <tr>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: score"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Can you guys help me out? I'm a bit new at Knockout so please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

**Edit**

Here's some more information:

```
 hs = [];
    getHighScores();

function getHighScores() {
        var highScoreArray = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: "../php/score_server.php",
            data: {
                "action": "getScore"
            },

            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
                var resultParsed = JSON.parse(result);
                $.each(resultParsed, function (key, value) {
                    hs.push(value);
                });
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            },
            async: true
        });
    }
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

There's some other bugs as well that I can not fix, like the `getHighScores()` being fired twice, although I call it only once... And it doesn't matter what the score is, The PHP document I call with my `sendHighScore()` function will always put **9** in the database. But I might open another question for that later.

**EDIT 2**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
        cW = ctx.canvas.width,
        cH = ctx.canvas.height,
        animateInterval,
        P,
        hs = [],
        paused = false;
    getHighScores();
    ko.applyBindings(new initCanvas());

    function getHighScores() {
        var highScoreArray = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: "../php/score_server.php",
            data: {
                "action": "getScore"
            },

            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
                var resultParsed = JSON.parse(result);
                $.each(resultParsed, function (key, value) {
                    hs.push(value);
                });
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            },
            async: true
        });
    }
    function initCanvas() {
        this.playerName = ko.observable("");
        this.chosenLevel = ko.observable();
        this.chosenDifficulty = ko.observable();

        this.availableLevels = ko.observableArray(['Mountains', 'Stars', 'Jungle']);
        this.difficulty = ko.observableArray(['Makkelijk', 'Normaal', 'Moeilijk']);
        this.highscores = ko.observableArray(hs);
        this.personalHighScore = ko.observable(localStorage.getItem("+score") || "Geen record!");
```

**Solution**

My fixed HTML:

```
<table>                     
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: highscores">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: score"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My fixed Javascript:

```
 function getHighScores() {
        var highScoreArray = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: "../php/score_server.php",
            data: {
                "action": "getScore"
            },

            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {

                var resultParsed = JSON.parse(result);
                $.each(resultParsed, function (key, value) {
                    hs.push(value);
                });
                ko.applyBindings(new initCanvas());
                $('#controls').find('input, select, button').prop('disabled', false);

            },

            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            },
            async: true
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code to where you make the server call to get the data?  Also how is `highscores` populated?

Comment: @BryantMiano I added some more information! Could you take another look at it ?

Comment: When do you call `initCanvas()`?  I think I have a feeling of whats wrong (you are not waiting to get the data from the server before you init your view model).  It might be easier to just post all of your JS code to get a better idea what is happening.

Comment: Edited even more. I have a lot of code and 99% of that code does not have anything to do with this issue. I hope what I have right now helps out, though! @BryantMiano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your viewmodel (initCanvas) the array `hs` is empty because it has not waited for the ajax call to complete.  On your success callback of your $.ajax is when you should `ko.applybindings`.  That way you actually have data in `hs` for knockout to bind:

```
            success: function (result) {
                var resultParsed = JSON.parse(result);
                $.each(resultParsed, function (key, value) {
                    hs.push(value);
                });
                ko.applyBindings(new initCanvas());

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to set the observable arrays value. Currently you are sort of defeating the purpose of using knockout by waiting for the post to return. It would look something like this.

Replace:

```
ko.applyBindings(new initCanvas());
```

in your original example with:

```
var canvasViewModel = new initCanvas();
ko.applyBindings(canvasViewModel);
```

and then in your success callback you would want to set the value of the observable like this:

```
canvasViewModel.highscores(resultParsed);
```

instead of

```
$.each(resultParsed, function (key, value) {
   hs.push(value);
});
ko.applyBindings(new initCanvas());
```